# Saving Bokeh widgets dynamic values

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I am new to java script so please forgive my ignorance.

I am using the example code from documentation.

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider

output_file("slider.html")

slider = Slider(start=0, end=10, value=1, step=.1, title="Stuff")

show(slider)
```

Whenever the slider is moved, the value next to "Stuff" changes which happens in JS I suppose.
Is there a way this dynamically changing value be stored in Python?

Answer (score 1):

"Storing in Python" implies that there is actually a Python process running, for the value to be stored in. But when you run a script like the one above, that is not the case. The sequence of events is:

- Python interpreter starts runs your script
- Static HTML/JS/CSS output is saved with the slider widget
- *Python process terminates*

So as it is, that is a non-starter. There has to be some persistent, long-running Python process for "Storing in Python" to make sense. That process is the [Bokeh Server](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) (it was created specifically to fill this role). A typical Bokeh server app version of your code might look like:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider

slider = Slider(start=0, end=10, value=1, step=.1, title="Stuff")

def callback(attr, old, new):
    # do something here with new slider values

slider.on_change('value', callback)

curdoc().add_root(slider)
```

And this would be run on the command line by using the `bokeh serve` command (not running as a "regular" Python script):

```
bokeh serve --show app.py
```

The `--show` will open a webbrowser automatically.

It is also possible to embed Bokeh server apps in Jupyter Notebooks. You can find an example notebook that you can run locally [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/notebook_embed.ipynb).